# Passing quotes in quotes to cmd.exe

Tags: parameters, cmd, quotes

I need to run `appcmd.exe` but running cmd.exe to query an IIS website and I also need to redirect the output.

The command should look like this:

```
cmd /c "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site MySite" > c:\output.txt
```

This works fine, however I encounter problems when I have spaces inside my paths, in which case I need to use quotes. Ideally, I would do:

```
cmd /c ""c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list site "MySite"" > "c:\output.txt"
```

but this doesn't work - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The help screen displayed by "cmd /c" shows this message:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
    on the command line are preserved:

    - no /S switch
    - exactly two quote characters
    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
      where special is one of: &<>()@^|
    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
      the two quote characters
    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
      of an executable file.

2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
    any text after the last quote character.
```

Use the "old" behavior mentioned in point 2. Type everything after /c as you would normally, but surround everything after /c in quotes. For example:

```
"c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list site "MySite" > "c:\output.txt"
```

becomes

```
cmd /c ""c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list site "MySite" > "c:\output.txt""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd /c c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site MySite > c:\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
cmd /c "'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe' list site 'MySite'" > "c:\output.txt"
```